# Mypy - why does TypeVar not work without bound specified

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to understand type annotations and I have the following code:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyClass():
    x: int = 10

def foo(obj: T) -> None:
    print(obj.x)

foo(MyClass())
```

[When I run mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=953d7485b2761092aa7b4a59914fc70f), I get the following error:

```
main.py:9: error: "T" has no attribute "x"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But when I add `bound='MyClass'` to the `TypeVar`, it shows no errors.

What is the reason for this behavior? I tried to read the documentation, but didn't find any answer on what exactly is happening when `bound` is set to a default value.

Comment: By default the `bound=object`. Only some `object`s have an attribute called `x`, not all. But all `MyClass`s have an attribute called `x`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This isn't what a `TypeVar` is usually used for.**

The following function is a good example of the kind of function that a `TypeVar` is typically used for:

```
def baz(obj):
    return obj
```

This function will work with an argument of any type, so one solution for annotating this function could be to use `typing.Any`, like so:

```
from typing import Any

def baz(obj: Any) -> Any:
    return obj
```

This isn't great, however. We generally should use `Any` as a last resort only, as it doesn't give the type-checker any information about the variables in our code. Lots of potential bugs will fly under the radar if we use `Any` too liberally, as the type-checker will essentially give up, and not check that portion of our code.

In this situation, there's a lot more information that we can feed to the type-checker. We don't know what the type of the input argument will be, and we don't know what the return type will be, but we do know that *the input type and the return type will be the same, whatever they are*. We can show this kind of relationship between types — a type-dependent relationship — by using a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def baz(obj: T) -> T:
    return obj
```

We can also use `TypeVar`s in similar, but more complex, situations. Consider this function, which will accept a sequence of any type, and construct a dictionary using that sequence:

```
def bar(some_sequence):
    return {some_sequence.index(elem): elem for elem in some_sequence}
```

We can annotate this function like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence

V = TypeVar('V')

def bar(some_sequence: Sequence[V]) -> dict[int, V]:
    return {some_sequence.index(elem): elem for elem in some_sequence}
```

Whatever the inferred type is of `some_sequence`'s elements, we can guarantee the values of the dictionary that is returned will be of the same type.

**Bound `TypeVar`s**

Bound `TypeVar`s are useful for when we have a function where we have some kind of type dependency like the above, but we want to narrow the types involved a little more. For example, imagine the following code:

```
class BreakfastFood:
    pass


class Spam(BreakfastFood):
    pass


class Bacon(BreakfastFood):
    pass


def breakfast_selection(food):
    if not isinstance(food, BreakfastFood):
        raise TypeError("NO.")
    # do some more stuff here
    return food
```

In this code, we've got a type-dependency like in the previous examples, but there's an extra complication: the function will throw a `TypeError` if the argument passed to it isn't an instance of — or an instance of a subclass of — the `BreakfastFood` class. In order for this function to pass a type-checker, we need to constrain the `TypeVar` we use to `BreakfastFood` and its subclasses. We can do this by using the `bound` keyword-argument:

```
from typing import TypeVar 


class BreakfastFood:
    pass


B = TypeVar('B', bound=BreakfastFood)


class Spam(BreakfastFood):
    pass


class Bacon(BreakfastFood):
    pass


def breakfast_selection(food: B) -> B:
    if not isinstance(food, BreakfastFood):
        raise TypeError("NO.")
    # do some more stuff here
    return food
```

**What's going on in your code**

If you annotate the `obj` argument in your `foo` function with an unbound `TypeVar`, you're telling the type-checker that `obj` could be of any type. But the type-checker correctly raises an error here: you've told it that `obj` could be of any type, yet your function assumes that `obj` has an attribute `x`, and not all objects in python have `x` attributes. By binding the `T` TypeVar to instances of — and instances of subclasses of — `MyClass`, we're telling  the type-checker that the `obj` argument should be an instance of `MyClass`, or an instance of a subclass of `MyClass`. All instances of `MyClass` and its subclasses have `x` attributes, so the type-checker is happy. Hooray!

However, your current function shouldn't really be using `TypeVar`s at all, in my opinion, as there's no kind of type-dependency involved in your function's annotation. If you know that the `obj` argument should be an instance of — or an instance of a subclass of — `MyClass`, and there is no type-dependency in your annotations, then you can simply annotate your function directly with `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass:
    x: int = 10

def foo(obj: MyClass) -> None:
    print(obj.x)

foo(MyClass())
```

If, on the other hand, `obj` doesn't need to be an instance of — or an instance of a subclass of — MyClass, and in fact any class with an `x` attribute will do, then you can use `typing.Protocol` to specify this:

```
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsXAttr(Protocol):
    x: int

class MyClass:
    x: int = 10

def foo(obj: SupportsXAttr) -> None:
    print(obj.x)

foo(MyClass())
```

Explaining `typing.Protocol` fully is beyond the scope of this already-long answer, but [here's](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/18/python-type-hints-duck-typing-with-protocol/) a great blog post on it.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem.

```
MyNewType = TypeVar("NewType", type_1_with_no_attribute, type_2_with_super_attribute)

def super_attribute_consumer(new_type_instance: MyNewType):
    print(new_type_instance.super_attribute)
```

MYPY throws error like

```
error: "type_1_with_no_attribute" has no attribute "super_attribute"
```

My solution is to adding `assert` sentence

```
def super_attribute_consumer(new_type_instance: MyNewType):
    assert isinstance(new_type_instance, type_2_with_super_attribute)
    print(new_type_instance.super_attribute)
```

MYPY will throw the error.